# how do I remove the outline of <b-dropdown-form>?

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-vue

Im using this

```
*{
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYqhO.png)

Comment: The focus ring is there for accessibility (i.e. keyboard only users) when using cursor UP/DOWN navigation of the menu items (the form is considered an item). Removing it will hinder those that cannot use a mouse or touchscreen. I wouldn't recommend removing it. It will only appear when using keyboard navigation or the user clicks the background of the menu.

Answer (score 0):

```
.dropdown-menu:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

one caveat, this will not work if placed in a Vue component's scoped style. You must use a [deep selector](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html), or place this in a non-scoped style block.